# Ubuntu black screen after Installation of 12.10 Live USB

Tags: 12.10

My computer was made in 2004, but I'm sure it doesn't matter since it's a durable machine. So recently, I decided to breathe new life to it with Linux. I tried Lubuntu 12.10, Nope. Black screen after install. So I tried Ubuntu 12.10 when I gave up, and same exact thing.
Except, this time I'm fighting for it, since Ubuntu is the best OS I've ever seen.

So back on-topic, when I start the installation, it says that something is already mounted
(Sda or something of the sorts)
So I just figure that it's the Live USB I'm using. So I let it ignore it, and move on. The rest of the installation goes smooth, all looks fine. Then I get to the screen with the introductory to Ubuntu. Meanwhile, it's still installing, but finishing up. I'm not sure if the install actually finishes, but I do know that after a bit, the screen goes back to the desktop. The install closes and I'm back at the desktop, and the cursor is showing the "loading" symbol, as if it were still working. Then the screen goes black, with the same cursor. After that, nothing. I left it over night like that thinking it was doing something, in the morning it was still black with the cursor circling or whatever.
So what could be causing this? One concern I have is that I have a Nvidia graphics card (7300 GT). I heard that Nvidia isn't compatible with Linux? I did notice that it was marked as unreconigsed by Ubuntu, so is that the problem perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I tried ubuntu and lubuntu. When I reboot is sais: "Searching for Boot Record from BSS-0"

**Update**

After a few hours of fiddling (using multiple version including alternate ones) I installed the server version (using a FAT formatted USB stick, not FAT32). Then at the command line I did: *sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop*